# copy specific row from one 2D array to another without system.arraycopy

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have to write a method that goes in array and goes from i to j rows and copies these rows to a new array. This is what I come up so far

```
 public static void getRows(int i, int j, int[][] array){
        int another[] = new int[j-i];
        int n = 0;
       for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
           while (i <= j){
               if (k == i){
                   another[n] = array[k][0];
               }
               i++;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How about [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(boolean[],%20int))?

Comment: how to do it.this code isn't working

Comment: @AndyTurner That's always my go-to when I need to avoid `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: What are you intending to do with `another`? You currently just discard it.

Comment: Lots of potential errors that you should check for: `i < 0` or `j < i` or `j >= array.length`

Comment: I have to write my own method can't use copyof or arraycopy

Comment: Also explain _"this code isn't working"_

Comment: well my new array is "another" , so I have to copy in it the rows from the first array

Comment: @AmilaBečirović yes. But you don't return it (or print it, or do anything with it).

Comment: I tried it and it gives me nothing in return

Comment: @AndyTurner I just tried to print it it gives me nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't returning or printing anything. Second, to copy multiple rows from your input your returned array should be 2d (not 1d). Create a `new int[][]` of `j - i` rows. Then copy from `array` to the new array. Something like,

```
public static int[][] getRows(int i, int j, int[][] array) {
    int[][] ret = new int[j - i][];
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
        ret[k - i] = new int[array[k].length];
        for (int m = 0; m < ret[k - i].length; m++) {
            ret[k - i][m] = array[k][m];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can invoke it (and print the results) with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] t = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 } };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(getRows(1, 3, t)));
}
```

Which outputs

```
[[2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks @Elliott :) .... after I post it I figured out that I didn't returned anything back , have done it a little bit different and instead of j-i I added plus 1 so that I will include the first row also

Answer (score 1):

@Elliot I did it like this :)

```js
 public static int[][] getRows(int i, int j, int[][] array){
        int[][] another = new int[j-i+1][];
        while (i <=j){
            for (int k = 0; k < another.length; k++){
                another[k]=array[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
        return another;
    }
```